# is I both a lower triang enad upper triangle ( Also proving L1=L2 )

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

First part of the question is
$$
A= L_1D_1U_1\\
A = L_2D_2U_2\\
Prove\\
L_1= L_2\\
D_1 = D_2 \\
U_1 = U_2 \\
$$

My attempt seems correct but not quire sure whether it's mathematically constructed.

$$
A^{-1} = U_1^{-1}D_1^{^-1}L_1^{-1}\\
AA^{-1} = I \\
I = L_2D_2U_2U_1^{-1}D_1^{^-1}L_1^{-1} \\
$$
So in order to and up with I

$$
L_1= L_2\\
D_1 = D_2 \\
U_1 = U_2 \\
$$

So that their inverses produce I

2nd part of the question is :

Derive the equation :
$$
L_1^{-1}L_2D_2 = D_1U_1U_2^{-1}
$$

and explain why one side is lower triangle and one side is upper triangle

I managed to derive the equation but couldn't explain "why one side is lower triangle and one is upper triangle" In the textbook it says that:

since $$L$$ is a lower triangle $$L^{-1}$$ is a lower triangle too. and multiplication of two lower triangles $$LL^{-1}$$ would be a lower triangle.

but isn't $$LL^{-1}= I $$ how come I can be lower triangle, isn't I both upper triangle and lower triangle?

Comment: Is $A$ nonsingular?

Comment: I guess yes since question gave out L U and D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$LDU$ decomposition actually exists for all square matrices even for singular matrices.

As for your question, since $I$ is both lower triangular and upper triangular (that is another way to say that it is diagonal), clearly, it is lower triangular.

$L_1^{-1}$ is lower triangular. $L$ is lower triangular too, $D_2$ is lower triangular too. Product of lower triangular matrices is a lower triangular matrix. Hence the LHS is lower triangular.

Similarly, RHS is upper triangular.

Implication, both sides are lower triangular and upper triangular, both sides are indeed diagonal.

Comment: Okay so you are saying that I is both lower triangular and upper triangular. But then how are we going to decide that the left side is lower triangular? I mean it comes from lower triangular * lower triangular I know, this would make it lower triangular but the answer of this multiplication in this case is I, it's the same case for the right hand side. I seriously didn't get how we can call the left side of the equation lower triangular but can't call the right hand side "lower triangular"

Comment: of course you can say the right hand side is lower triangular, in fact, you can say that it is diagonal.

Comment: Suppose for some weird reason that you do not know $L_1=L_2$ and $U_1=U_2$. Then it is natural to conclude that the LHS is lower triangular. 
The RHS is upper triangular.  Since they are equal, they are diagonal.